# How to size a table to the page width in MigraDoc?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am trying to resize a table automatically to full width of the page. That table should have 2 columns, 50% width each.

How can I achieve this? I tried LeftIndent and RightIndent properties with no luck.

Comment: posting some of you current code might help us.....

Answer (score 31):

Here's an approach that avoids hardcoding widths and allows for more flexible paper formats. Make sure to include the `using MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel;` statement in your class.

```
Document document = new Document();

Section section = document.AddSection();

section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();
section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;

Table table = section.AddTable();

float sectionWidth = section.PageSetup.PageWidth - section.PageSetup.LeftMargin - section.PageSetup.RightMargin;
float columnWidth = sectionWidth / 2;

Column column = table.AddColumn();
column.Width = columnWidth;
Column column2 = table.AddColumn();
column2.Width = columnWidth;

Row row = table.AddRow();
row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Row 1, Column A");
row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Row 1, Column B");
```

Comment: It should be noted that this works only if `PageSetup.PageWidth`, `PageSetup.LeftMargin` and `PageSetup.RightMargin` where previously assigned. If you want to use the default values for `PageSetup`, assign `DefaultPageSetup.Clone()` to the `PageSetup` of the section.

Comment: Add `section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();` before `section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use percent values with MigraDoc.
You can set the absolute width of each column.

So when using DIN A4 with 2.5 cm margin at each side, you have 16 cm left for the table and so you have to create two columns of 8 cm each.

You can set the left indent of the table to move tables horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer from *Kidquick* does not work, use document.DefaultPageSetup:

```
document.DefaultPageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;

int sectionWidth = (int)document.DefaultPageSetup.PageWidth - (int)document.DefaultPageSetup.LeftMargin - (int)document.DefaultPageSetup.RightMargin;

Table table = section.AddTable();
table.AddColumn(sectionWidth);
Row row = table.AddRow();
row.Height = 60;
```

Comment: The `DefaultPaegSetup` should never be modified. A `Clone()` of `DefaultPageSetup` can be assigned to the PageSetup of the session and can be modified as needed.