# MigraDoc section width

Tags: c#, migradoc

I wanted a method to set relative column width in MigraDoc, and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986424/how-to-size-a-table-to-the-page-width-in-pdfsharp) on the subject. The problem is, it does not work for me. I have copied the exact code from that post:

```
Section section = document.AddSection();
section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;

int sectionWidth = (int)(section.PageSetup.PageWidth - section.PageSetup.LeftMargin - section.PageSetup.RightMargin);
int columnWidth = sectionWidth / 2;
```

However, if I insert a breakpoint in the code (right after `int columnWidth = ...`), it states that the section page width is zero:

[image: Screenshot of Output]

So obviously everything which is derived from the section width, also becomes zero. But why? As you can see, the `PageFormat` is correctly set to "A4". I don't get it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a solution (a bit by coincidence). This post describes a somewhat similar issue with `section.PageSetup`. The solutions is to create a clone of the default page setup, before modifying it. The new code looks like this:

```
Section section = document.AddSection();
section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone(); // <-- This has been added
section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;

int sectionWidth = (int)(section.PageSetup.PageWidth - section.PageSetup.LeftMargin - section.PageSetup.RightMargin);
int columnWidth = sectionWidth / 2;
```